# PHP Content-Disposition: attachment works locally but not on server

Tags: php, csv, http-headers

What i am doing is querying the database to build a CSV file.  I am using these headers to save the file:

```
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="export.csv"');
```

It's is working locally on my WAMP setup but not on the server.  Is there a setting or something in PHP or Apache that i need to change to allow for this?

When i click the link locally it downloads a CSV file.  When i do the same thing on the live server it just brings me to the php page that is generating the CSV content.

Comment: Do you get any error messages? Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of your script - my guess is that you will see `Cannot modify header information: headers already sent in...`

Comment: You are correct about that.  How can i fix this?  And why didn't i see this in my local environment?

Comment: Well I'd guess that your WAMP server setup has output buffering enabled, allowing you to modify the headers after you have sent some content. Since you say this works on your local setup I'm guessing that the additional output is just white space, the usual culprit of which is that you have some white space outside the `<?php ?>` tags in your file. Make sure that the `<` of the opening `<?php` is *the first* character in the file, and the `>` of the `?>` is *very last*. This also applies to included files. Also check if your editor is saving files with a BOM (which it shouldn't be)

Comment: Didn't look like there was any white space.  Could it be caused because those headers lines are after some includes?  Should they be the first lines on the page?

Comment: Maybe, it depends if your script does anything else. If it might also output a web page (which sounds like it might be the case) then you don't want to send the wrong headers when it does that. Can you show you code?

Comment: I moved the headers to the top of the code and that fixed it.  I think that was the culprit.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: No worries, although if you want to find the cause of the problem, the file/line no where the output started (and therefore the cause of the problem) should be in the error message - it will show two file/line no refs, one on the line where you called `header()` and one where the output was started, preventing the `header()` call from succeeding

Comment: Thanks! I'll research more into it.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `application/octet-stream` not `text/csv`. I don't know why your browser behaves differently for different domains, but it is more common to use `application/octet-stream`. This is mentioned in [RFC2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html). As you're not displaying it in the browser, the content-type doesn't have to match the content anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem as you. In my case, the solution is that we just have to use
`include 'connection_file.php';`
after

```
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv');
```

Means your header files must be the first statement of the file.

Complete PHP code to export csv is :

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['Export'])){

      header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
      header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv');

      include '../dbcon.php';

      $output = fopen("php://output", "w");
      fputcsv($output, array('id', 'name', 'phone', 'Employee Name', 'district', 'taluka', 'address'));
      $query = "SELECT * from export_buffer ORDER BY id DESC";
      $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
      {
           fputcsv($output, $row);
      }
      fclose($output);
 }
?>
```